# searching strings for keywords: questions about the "failure function"

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I've got a question on failure function description from "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools" aka DragonBook

Firstly, the quote:

> In order to process text strings rapidly and search those strings for a keyword,
>   it is useful to define, for keyword b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>n</sub>, and position s in that keyword , a failure function, f (s) ...
>    The objective is that b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>.. - b<sub>f(s)</sub> is the longest proper prefix of
>   b<sub>1</sub>...b<sub>s</sub>, that is also a suffix of b<sub>1</sub>...b<sub>s</sub>. The reason f (s) is important is that
>   if we are trying to match a text string for b<sub>l</sub>b<sub>2</sub>..b<sub>n</sub>, and we have matched the
>   first s positions, but we then fail (i.e., the next position of the text string does
>   not hold b<sub>s+l</sub>), then f (s) is the longest prefix of b<sub>1</sub>..b<sub>n</sub> that could possibly
>   match the text string up to the point we are at. Of course, the next character of
>   the text string must be b<sub>f(s)+1</sub> or else we still have problems and must consider
>   a yet shorter prefix, which will be b<sub>f(f(s))</sub>.

So, the questions:
1. If we've matched s positions with the text, why f (s) is the *longest* prefix of b<sub>1</sub>..b<sub>n</sub> that matches the string? I think s - is the longest prefix.
2. Next character of the text string must be b<sub>f(s)+1</sub>, why? We have a mismatch at this position, does it matter at all what the char is?

Answer (score 2):

f(s) is the longest prefix at that position that might match the entire keyword. The idea is not to try to match the keyword with the text from the start, but to find a position where the keyword appears.

Consider a search for the word 'aaaba' in the text 'aaaabaa'. The match fails after the three first a's, but it's not necessary to retry from the second 'a', since we know that if the next letter is a 'b' (which it is), we may have a match there.